# Homotopy equivalence between three touching circles and bouquet

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The task is to prove that three touching in a row circles homotopy equivalent to bouquet of three circles using the definition of homotopy equivalence. Unfortunately I cant use another theorems, such that if a pair $(X,A)$ has the homotopy extension property and $A$ is contractible, then the quotient map $q:X \rightarrow X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Let X be the space of three touching circles and Y be the bouquet, i.e. 
$$X := (\mathbb{S}^1 \lor \mathbb{S}^1) \lor \mathbb{S}^1 ,\quad Y := \mathbb{S}^1 \lor \mathbb{S}^1 \lor \mathbb{S}^1.$$

To prove their homotopy equivalence I need to find $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow X$, such that $f \circ g \simeq \mathrm{id}_Y$ and $g \circ f \simeq \mathrm{id}_X$, where $\simeq$ is homotopic relation.

So far so good I think only these maps make sense to the task: [(click for image).](https://pp.vk.me/c621122/v621122913/a92/NPRBi3POFu4.jpg) $_{\text{I'm sorry, I cant post images, reputation is too low.}}$

Both maps are continious. As you see, the image of bottom arc $\beta_2$ of red circle is contracted to $f(\beta_2) = f(B) = f(A)$. But the image of blue petal $\theta$ from bouquet is stretched starting from $g(C)$ along the half of middle circle, then to the right circle, then again to the middle and, finally, to $g(C)$.

It turns out, that $f \circ g : Y \rightarrow Y$ and $g \circ f : X \rightarrow X$ look like this: [(click for image).](https://pp.vk.me/c621122/v621122913/a9c/P4CMNAYRWYI.jpg)

(Note, that every time image of blue curve is making a twist around another curve.)
I need help in prooving that they are homotopic to $\mathrm{id}_Y$ and $\mathrm{id}_X$ respectively, couldnt do it by myself. To contract that blue extra loop I need to cut it somewhere, but that is not how homotopy works. Every advice will be much appreciated.

$_{\text{Sorry for bad English, not my native language}}$

Comment: Your pictures do not give enough information to know how your maps are defined. There is a better convention to describe maps between graphs: orient and name all edges in the domain; orient and name all edges in the range; and then, for each edge in the domain, name the map on this edge as a concatenation of edges in the range.