# Homotopy equivalence: three touching circles vs 3-bouquet

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Are these two spaces homotopic equivalent? This question is already posed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709629/homotopy-equivalence-between-three-touching-circles-and-bouquet) but the answer is missing.

[image]

Comment: Based-equivalence or not?

Comment: @Randall not based-equivalence

Comment: See Hatcher's discussion *Collapsing Subspaces* on page 11 of his book. The statement in italics is what I am referring to especially.

Comment: @Tyrone good, so we can insert a segment between contact point of circles obtaining two graph like these https://imgur.com/TcaxUeB ?

Comment: Take the figure on the right. Give the middle $S^1$ the CW structure with two 0-cells and two 1-cells. Now collapse one of the 1-cells to a point. You get the figure on the left. Quote Hatcher. (Edit: this would be what Andres has written in his answer)

Comment: Yes! Thank you both, I perfectly got it, thanks for that reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for the right hand picture, give each $S^1$ a CW-structure of two $0$-cells on the equator, and the two $1$-cells connecting them. Take any spanning tree of the complex and contract it to a point. One idea is to take the union of bottom hemispheres of each $S^1$, and pinch them to a point.